# Quick question regarding the angle when converting from complex to polar/exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried to google this, because it seems really simple but I couldn't get a clear answer.

I have an old test with the question $z = 1 + i$ write $z$ in exponential form.

For this you need $r$ and angle.

I know how to find $r$ ( $\sqrt2$ ) but I have angle as $\pi/4$ and I don't know how I found that, and then a question later I have $z = 3i$ and angle there is $\pi/2$.

How do you find that angle? Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument).

Answer (score 0):

Notice, argument of $z=x+iy$ is given as $$\arg(x+iy)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\ \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x\ge0, y\ge0 $$
$0\le\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\le \frac{\pi}{2}$

hence, one should get 
$$\arg(1+i)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\arg(3i)=\arg(0+3i)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{0}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\infty\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: *Caveat:* You have to be careful in choosing the correct value of $\tan^{-1}\frac yx$.  For example, $\tan \frac{5\pi}4 = 1$ too, but that angle is wrong.

Comment: @MPW: please note that he assumed the OP 're working on first quadrant of the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let z = x + iy.
Traditional way is to calculate $\tan(\arg z)=\dfrac yx$ and then to look for right quadrant. That situation takes place, because $\tan$ function has period $\pi$ while we are interested in argument with period $2\pi$.

The suitable decision is to calculate
$\tan\dfrac{\arg z}2=\dfrac y{x+r},\quad$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = |z|$.
So, required formila is:
$\boxed{\arg z = 2\arctan{\dfrac y{x+r}}},$ where $x=\Re z,\quad y=\Im z,\quad r=|z|$.
I.e.:
$\arg (1+i) = 2\arctan\dfrac1{1+\sqrt2} = \dfrac{\pi}4;$
$\arg (0+3i) = 2\arctan\dfrac3{0+3} = 2\arctan(1) = \dfrac{\pi}2;$
$\arg (-1+i) = 2\arctan\dfrac1{-1+\sqrt2} = \dfrac{3\pi}4;$
$\arg (-1-i) = 2\arctan\dfrac{-1}{-1+\sqrt2} = -\dfrac{3\pi}4.$
Boxed formula doesn't work when $x+r=0,$ that case means that $\arg z=\pi$.